# How to disallow some items of combobox to be selected

Tags: c#, extjs

I have a combobox and combostore is fetched from database.
I do not want user to select a value called 'something'.

If user tries to sleect the item, the combobox will reset back to last values selected or simply blank.

```
{ fieldLabel: 'Items', 
    listeners: {
                select: function (combo, record) {
                    if (combo.value == 'something') {
                        retrun false;
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Also as the combo store is fetched from database, I cant delete this item from store.
Any one can tell me the solution or any alternative to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by replacing `retrun false;` with `combo.setValue(null);`

```
{ 
    fieldLabel: 'Items', 
           listeners: {
                select: function (combo, record) {
                    if (combo.value == 'something') {
                        retrun false;
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

combo.setValue(null) makes the combo box blank.Is there any way to set the previously selected value?I can get the previously selected value in change event but not able to get it in select event.So is there any way to set the previously selected value in select event?